# Accessing data status with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following to set up a simple AJAX call:

```
            if(validateEmail(email_val)){

                $.post($('#form_url').val(), { email: email_val }, function(data) { 
                    console.log(data);
                 } );

            }
```

It all works but how I can access "status":true?

I want to do:

```
if(status is true){ call this function }

if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {                
            $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(
                                            array(
                                                 'field'   => 'email',
                                                 'label'   => 'Email',
                                                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email'
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        );

            if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                $data = array('status' => FALSE, 'error' => $this->form_validation->error_array());
            }
            else {
                if($this->pages->addEntry()==true){
                    $data = array('status' => TRUE, 'error' => FALSE);
                } else {
                    $data = array('status' => FALSE, 'error' => 'You already participate in the competition');                
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($data); 
        } else {
            $dupe = false;
            if(is_numeric($id)) {
                $this->page = $this->pages->getSingleById($id, array('timestamps' => 2, 'files' => 5, 'longtexts' => 2, 'varchars' => 3));
                $this->page["timeLeft"] = $this->pages->countLeftTime($this->page["timestamps_1"]);
            } else {
                $this->page = $this->pages->getCurrentCompetition();
            }

            $this->view_vars = array(
                'page'  => $this->page,
                'dupe'  => $dupe,
                'signed_request'    => $_REQUEST['signed_request'],
            );

            return $this->load->view('html/pages/index', $this->view_vars);
        }
```

Comment: What does the serverside code look like?

Comment: What status exactly? The function will be called only if the request is successful i.e. status 200, any other status will be silently ignored in this simple form of AJAX.

Comment: if the email sent through is successful than call function

Comment: Just do `if ( $_POST['email'] )` instead ?

Comment: I can't touch the back end unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post($('#form_url').val(), { email: email_val },function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

data - contains the resulting data from the request

status - contains the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", or "parsererror")

If you wanna return code execution status at server side then return value in data like 'success' or true, or 1 or 0 and compare same value at client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  $("#log").html( msg );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

request.always(function(){
 alert('Ajax complete');
});
```

reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In the .done callback you chould query the object that your server returns and check the value you want.

```
if (msg.status == "something") {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean your status is in the data that you receive, then you can just do "data.status". You would not need anything further.